# Swift: Saving Firebase data to CoreData in async operation

Tags: ios, firebase, core-data

I am attempting to pull data from Firebase and then save it to CoreData but am having trouble with the async operation. I have a custom function that returns `[ConversationStruct]` upon completion. I then do a `forEach` to save it to CoreData.

However, my current implementation saves the object multiple times, ie Firebase have 10 entries, but CoreData would somehow give me 40 over entries which most are repeated. I suspect the problem is in my `completionHandler`.

```
//At ViewDidLoad of my VC when I pull the conversations from Firebase
FirebaseClient.shared.getConversationsForCoreData(userUID) { (results, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else if let results = results {
        print(results.count)

        let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateContext.parent = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

        results.forEach({ (c) in

            let conversation = Conversation(context: privateContext)
            conversation.conversationStartTime = c.conversationStartTime
            conversation.recipientID = c.recipientID
            conversation.shoutoutID = c.shoutoutID
            conversation.unreadMessagesCount = Int32(c.unreadMessagesCount!)
            conversation.profileImage = c.profileImage
            conversation.recipientUsername = c.recipientUsername
        })

        do {
            try privateContext.save()

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

//At FirebaseClient
func getConversationsForCoreData(_ userUID: String, _ completionHandler: @escaping (_ conversations: [ConversationStruct]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    var conversations = [ConversationStruct]()

    ref.child("conversations").child(userUID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children {
            let snapDatasnapshot = snap as! DataSnapshot
            let snapValues = snapDatasnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            let recipientUID = snapDatasnapshot.key

            for (key, value) in snapValues {
                //Some other logic

                self.getUserInfo(recipientUID, { (results, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else if let results = results {
                        let username = results["username"] as! String
                        let profileImageUrl = results["profileImageUrl"] as! String

                        URLClient.shared.getImageData(profileImageUrl, { (data, error) in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            } else if let imageData = data {
                                let convo = ConversationStruct(conversationStartTime: conversationStartTime, shoutoutID: shoutoutID, recipientID: shoutoutID, unreadMessagesCount: unreadMessagesCount, recipientUsername: username, profileImage: imageData)
                                conversations.append(convo)

                            }

                            completionHandler(conversations, nil)

                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ConversationStruct {
    var conversationStartTime: Double
    var shoutoutID: String
    var recipientID: String
    var unreadMessagesCount: Int?
    var recipientUsername: String?
    var profileImage: Data?
}
```

The print statement would print the count as and when the operation completes. This seems to tell me that privateContext is saving the entities when the results are consistently being downloaded which resulted in 40 over entries. Would anyone be able to point me out in the right direction how to resolve this?

Also, the implementation does not persist.

Comment: Did you Try to put private context globally

Comment: And one more thing you are repeatedly calling completion handler because it is in for loop. My suggestion is you should first fetch all data using Dispatch Group and on notify of group event you should only call completion handler once

Comment: Suppose a condition where your `results.forEach` is executing mean time 10 completion handler  called ?. so it should be only once and only one time add all the data to core data. however you can also take advantage of  firebase local storage if you need local functionality :)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya thanks for your reply. I'm really pretty rookie here so I don quite understand what you are saying. Mind showing some code which I can try out?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya so where can i call the completionHandler? If i call at any places outside the async operation there wont be any objects as the operation is still ongoing.